# Timezone confusion with date picker and UTC times

Tags: json, datepicker, utc

I have a web page with a DatePicker control (from Kendo UI) on it.

Firstly, I'm in New Zealand, which is UTC +12:00

When I select a date of 31st October 2012 in my date picker, it gets stored in the JavaScript object as:

Wed Oct 31 00:00:00 UTC+1300 2012

This seems wrong!

It gets serialized to JSON (using JSON.stringify) as 2012-10-30T11:00:00.000Z, which is wrong.

Back on the server, when the JSON is parsed, this comes out at 30th October 2012, 23:00.

Can somebody explain this to me? And what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this figured out now - the date picker control is working correctly, as for the date of October 31st, New Zealand will be in Daylight Savings Time, so at that date, we will be UTC +1300.

My problem is that my server code is converting to UTC on the basis of today's date, rather than using the offset as it would be on the the actual date.